# Cannot create a Directory in OS X with boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, permissions, directory, osx-yosemite

I want to create a Directory on OS X using boost::filesystem.  Here is my code:

```
  boost::filesystem::path p("/foo/bar");

  const char* path = p.c_str();
  boost::filesystem::path dir(path);
  if(boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir))
  {
    std::cerr<< "Directory Created: "<<p<<std::endl;
  }
```

Every time I get the `Directory Created: "/foo/bar"` but nothing is created.  I tried also to made the foo directory manually and set the permissions to `"Read & Write"` for everyone but it still won't create `/bar`.

Any help would be great

EDIT:

I just wrote a command line app that successfully creates the desired directory.  My issue must be related to permissions and the VST/ DAW (Ableton Live) - see comments.

I'll report the solution when I find it

Comment: Are you running as a privileged (root) user?

Comment: It's confusing when you say "it still won't create `/bar`". You didn't ask for that. Neither do the permissions on `/foo` matter there :)

Comment: @rholmes Well, I am making a VST plugin and that runs in a VST host called Ableton Live.  Perhaps that's the problem and I need to Google about Ableton's VST permissions

Comment: Perhaps... I would think that you'd want to store data in a writable location in that case...

Comment: @sehe Sorry, I mean it won't create `/foo/bar` whether or not `/foo` exists already.  HTH

Comment: @rholmes I probably need to research more.  I'll have a Google